# Operator ? : surprise, surprise

Tags: c#, syntax-error

Imagine situation

```
int? customerId = null; // works fine
int? customerId = 5; // also fine
int? customerId = someCondition ? 5 : null; // There is no implicit conversion between int and null
int? customerId = someCondition ? 5 : (int?)null; // now is ok
```

How is this possible? Is it the language specification? For me the obvious would be implicit conversion. What do you think?

Comment: My guess is that there is not implicit conversion between int and null because int is a value type and not an object type.

Comment: This has been asked many times before. `a?b:c`'s result type will be either the type of `b`, or the type of `c`. If neither of those types is possible, your code has an error. Let me find a duplicate.

Comment: I agree but there is nullable int as l-value type

Comment: `Nullable<T>` has implemented the implicit and explicit operator for type convertion, but not `null` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986458(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @stanke Neither the second nor the third operand of your failing `?:` expression has type `int?`, so type `int?` is not considered.

Comment: @hvd, I didn't know how to search for this. Thanks for the quick answer!